24.04. LTS No audio nor audio devices
I've been looking this and other forums for help with my problem. I just cannot find accurate help for my case. Many similar cases, but Youtube self help videos just are not working. Wrong codes for command prompt etc. So, sorry if this audio thing pop ups again for somebody.
I bought brand new MSI Z17 creator laptop. Installed Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04. LTS side by side. This worked so far. Then I found out that the audio was not working well from the laptops own speakers on Ubuntu. Sound was just bad quality, not bright as when using headset.
So I started to toggle pulseaudio, alsamixer, pipewire you name it. And for some reason I even managed to uninstall my desktop (three times!-> Running sudo apt remove pipewire attempts to remove ubuntu-desktop and other core functionality causing the login screen not to come up). At the moment the case is that I wish to go back to factory settings with this audio problem.

Ubuntu is not finding in or output devices by itself (see code underneath)
I managed to unmask pulseaudio. The audio settings were looking ok for a moment although no sounds came or mic worked.
With Alsamixer I can see that Pipewire or Nvidia have been default soundcard. Not as it was.
I get the pulse audio visually work with the following:

systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio.socket
pulseaudio --start
I am asking for a simple guideline to get to basic settings without needing to reinstall Ubuntu. And if you are able to provide help to the bad audio quality, that would be a great plus.

Please provide the output of the following commands, it would give us a better understanding of what is failing:
journalctl --user -u pulseaudio --no-pager , systemctl --user status pulseaudio pipewire , inxi -A and sudo alsa-info.sh --upload

I got it work somehow, but it is ok and good broach to double check the case anyway. Thanks.
~$ journalctl --user -u pulseaudio --no-pager
elo 23 00:41:11 Endeavour systemd[2010]: Starting pulseaudio.service - Sound Service...
elo 23 00:41:13 Endeavour systemd[2010]: Started pulseaudio.service - Sound Service.
elo 23 00:55:11 Endeavour systemd[2010]: pulseaudio.service: Consumed 1min 9.188s CPU time, 10.7M memory peak, 0B memory swap peak.

-- Boot 536ea7345b764109a22b31f5e95d6f22 --
elo 23 01:53:03 Endeavour systemd[2651]: Starting pulseaudio.service - Sound Service...
elo 23 01:53:03 Endeavour pulseaudio[13220]: Daemon already running.
elo 23 01:53:03 Endeavour pulseaudio[13220]: pa_pid_file_create() epäonnistui.
elo 23 01:53:03 Endeavour systemd[2651]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
elo 23 01:53:03 Endeavour systemd[2651]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
elo 23 01:53:03 Endeavour systemd[2651]: Failed to start pulseaudio.service - Sound Service.

Systemctl command is not working:
ystemctl --user status pulseaudio pipewire
Komentoa 'ystemctl' ei löydy, tarkoititko:
komento 'systemctl' deb-paketista systemd (255.4-1ubuntu8.4)
komento 'systemctl' deb-paketista systemctl (1.4.4181-1.1)
Kokeile: sudo apt install 

inxi -A
Audio:
Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake High Definition Audio
driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-41-generic status: kernel-api
Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.7 status: active

sudo alsa-info.sh --upload <- this command is not working.

Good, you got it to work. But there are errors in the command. Pardon me, but what language is the OS in? I haven't been able to translate some keywords to English, I need that to pin-point the cause of the error.

It is in Finnish.
